# Core Data Count (Or distinct)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a table with a about 100 rows.  One of the columns has a column named "MeetingType"  which is always an int value (1, 2, or 3)

How could I create a fetch predicate that would return a count a of how many rows had a different type?

For example if out of the 100 rows, 50 had a type = 0 and 25 had a type=1 and the remaining 25 had a type=2.  a results set would be a count of 3.  (showing that there were 3 different types in all the rows)

Answer (score 5):

Here is simple and pure `NSFetchRequest` version:

```
    NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Meeting"];
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"MeetingType"]];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"MeetingType"]];
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSUInteger count = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] count];
```

Answer (score 1):

fetch the results as a set, then count the number of items in the set.

Edit #2: There is also the following link which should help you get a more concise way of doing this. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE

Edit: ok, here is an attempt at it.

```
//you will be working on some sort of entity, i've guessed its called Meeting
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Meeting" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

//you can set a predicate here if you like, eg only meetings with a certain name or something
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", type_name];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
// Specify that the request should return dictionaries.
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

// Create an expression for the key path, in this case MeetingType
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"MeetingType"];


// Create an expression description using the maxExpression and returning a date.
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

// The name is the key that will be used in the dictionary for the return value.
[expressionDescription setName:@"meetingTypes"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:keyPathExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType];

// Set the request's properties to fetch just the property represented by the expressions.
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [sharedAISDataService.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];    

//check for no error
if(error == nil){
     //the following set will contain unique NSNumber objects
     NSSet *setOfMeetinTypes = [NSSet setWithArray:objects];

     int numberOfMeetinTypes = [setOfMeetinTypes count];
     //you now have the number of unique meeting types

}
```

Comment: Could you show me an example. I'm so new to the core data and especially predicates that I still have trouble creating them from scratch.  Thanks again.

Comment: ooh, i wont be able to get it syntactically correct off of the top of my head, but i should be able to give you enough to go on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to counting in the set, you could do three count fetches.

```
NSError *error;
int count;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([yourObject class])];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"MeetingType == 1"];
count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (count > 0) {
    //Add 1 to your set or handle appropriately
}

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"MeetingType == 2"];
count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (count > 0) {
    //Add 2 to your set or handle appropriately
}

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"MeetingType == 3"];
count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (count > 0) {
    //Add 3 to your set or handle appropriately
}
```

This should be a lot faster than actually pulling objects out and searching in that set for ones with the different MeetingType attributes.